# reducer default implementation via ngrx schematics

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am trying to create a reducer via ngrx schematics command

```
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:reducer ZipCodes --group
```

Which is creating a reducer file with **NO** default implementation of reducer

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
);
```

ideally it should be like below

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {

    default:
      return state;
  }
```

could anyone help. not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything.

We (the NgRx Team) encourage to use the new syntax of declaring reducers, using `createReducer`. The reducer using the switch statement is the older syntax.

https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/you-should-take-advantage-of-the-improved-ngrx-apis#reducers